# Chrome extension JSONP request access global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, jsonp

I'm using JSONP in a google chrome extension.
In order to make it work, i had to add

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);
```

and then make the request like this:

```
var jsonpURL;
$(document).ready(function(){
   /* i make the "someurl" here from a div's content */
   jsonpURL="someurl";
   chrome.extension.sendRequest({action:'getJSON',url:jsonpURL});
});
```

and the problem is, i cant acces the `jsonpURL` variable in the request:

```
function onRequest(request, sender, callback) {
    alert(jsonpURL);
}
```

**Undefinied.**

seems like the `jsonpURL` variable has no value at the request despite i start it only after i gave value to the `jsonpURL` variable in the ready function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.url should be equal to jsonpURL in your onRequest function.